# Communication between 2 wars in the same Java Servlet Container

Tags: java, web, tomcat, war, java-ee-7

How do I call a war endpoint from a war that is running in the same server? The same way a client would do or is there any way of doing this interaction more "light" (without involving HTTP).

I know that I could use some libraries like resteasy client library but I was wondering if there is a more straightforward way

Comment: Plenty of other ways: Local sockets, websockets, even RMI (don't use RMI). But it sounds like the easiest way is just to call that endpoint over HTTP.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.